# Cassandra execute something if values exist

Tags: asynchronous, cassandra, exists

I'm new to Cassandra and therefore my question may seam silly. My scenario is:

I have a table that stores meteorological data. One column is the wind velocity in North-to-South direction, one other the wind velocity in East-to-West direction. The values come into these columns from independent sources and because of that they are entered into this table asynchronously. My task is to calculate the total wind velocity by adding the squares for these two measures and calculate the square root of this sum. And this, of course, I can only do when I'm sure that both values are set. How can I configure that out?

Many thanks in advance,
Christian

Answer (score 0):

What you want is CAS (Compare and set), also called lightweight transactions. It's easy to use, just use the keywords IF EXISTS at the end of your query. Here is some documentation: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_ltweight_transaction_t.html